# Company profile API:LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

Can anyone one tell how to get the company Company,Name,Title,Email Address,Physical Address,Company Type, and more from linkedIn through any API

Answer (score 4):

LinkedIn has added the Company API as of May 2011.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields

I'm using the Company API through Python and getting good results. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Now they allow searching companies by keywords:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search